# Address info from event_list_attendees

Tags: eventbrite

Is there a way to get attendee address information out of event_list_attendees without first customizing the order form for the event? If not, is it possible to customize the order form for an event from the API?  I didn't notice that functionality when looking over the list of methods, and it seems strange that I would have to have my users go to the EventBrite website after creating an event through some of the software that I've written.

Comment: I asked this question via direct email to EventBrite, and tweeting at their @EventbriteAPI twitter account as well. No answers from EventBrite, and we are now looking at alternatives from EventBrite due to poor developer support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your order form didn't already ask the attendee for their address information, then there's no way to get it from the attendee list.

Currently, there is no way to customize the order form from the API.

Comment: Yep, we dropped eventbrite due to poor support already though. Thanks!